# Ajax call for form submit not returning the original response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax call for submitting my form like this,

```
$.ajax({
    url: $("#"+formId).attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#"+formId).serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);                  
    }
});
```

I have returned one string value in the form action method(this method is Spring annotation). But here everything works fine(my form also submitted well) except that return value. It returns Xmldocumnet as response in that response also that String value was not found. How can i get my original return value here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `dataType` to tell jQuery what you are expecting.
From [**Doc**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String
>     The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
>   MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4
>   JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the
>   script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

If you are expecting plain string use

```
$.ajax({   
        // Other attributes  
        dataType: "text"  
});
```